# Seasonal ARIMA estimate with non-significant variance

Tags: variance, arima, seasonality

I'm trying to fit a seasonal ARIMA model for a real data time series, 300 samples long, sawtooth looking. I'll write down a resume of my work trying to be clear without many plots.

The ACF of the original data slowly tapering towards 0 and the value PACF(1)=0.8 both suggest a non-seasonal differencing of order 1. As a consequence, both ACF and PACF correlations of the differencied data fall in the 95% confidence interval except for ACF(43)=+0.5 and PACF(~40)=-0.3. This value roughly corresponds to the period of my spikes in the signal.

I therefore applied a seasonal differencing for seasonality=43 multiplied by the non-seas. differencing. The correlograms follow:
[image: correlograms]

What are the negative correlations at lag=1 telling me, now? Maybe differencing is too much and an AR(1) should be employed?

However, I tried some models with combinations of AR(1), MA(1), SAR(1) and SMA(1) and I got from minimization of AIC and BIC the following best models:

$$(1,0,0)\times(0,1,1)_{43}$$
$$(1,0,1)\times(0,1,0)_{43}$$
$$(1,0,0)\times(0,1,0)_{43}$$

For example, the residuals correlograms for the latter:
[image: residuals correlograms for best fit]

which look not bad to me even though some significant spikes around the lag of seasonality remain. Can be this due to the **imperfect seasonality** (data are from extremely fine sampled measurements!)? 
Anyway, I have other two concerns:

- the estimated variance of the model is $\sigma=1.7\times 10^{-10}$ with st. error$=4.6\times 10^{-8}$ which gives a t-statistic$=0.002$ really low!
- the qq-plot of residuals shows a non-agreement with the Gaussian distribution:

[image: qq-plot for best fit]

In conclusion, how much can I trust my estimated model given these two problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not at all !  Your data might disclose changes in parameters over time or deterministic changes in error variance over time suggesting Weighted Least  Squares or the need to identify and incorporate latent deterministic structure like pulses, step/level shifts or local time trends OR the need to incorporate seasonal dummies to deal with seasonal structure (often a good choice ! ).

Post your data and let's find out what your data knows.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF YOUR DATA:

To review , auto.arima in a brute force list-based procedure that tries a fixed set of models and selects the calculated AIC based upon estimated parameters. The AIC should be calculated from residuals using models that control for intervention administration, otherwise the intervention effects are taken to be Gaussian noise, underestimating the actual model's autoregressive effect and thus miscalculates the model parameters which leads directly to an incorrect error sum of squares and ultimately an incorrect AIC.

The acf of the original is useful in assessing ARIMA structure ( that's the big  print ! ) when there are no deterministic factors/features in play like period # 
( that's the small print ! ) . Here is the acf of the original data [image] .

Your 301 values are indeed non-stationary BUT there is more than 1 remedy for non-stationarity. Your series has deterministic effects for certain periods in the 43 period cycle . See [I have correlogram ACF and PACF below for a temperature time series. Can I say it is MA(2) from ACF? What about AR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319732/i-have-correlogram-acf-and-pacf-below-for-a-temperature-time-series-can-i-say-i/319745#319745) for a similar but different but related discussion.

I took your 301 values into AUTOBOX a piece of software that I had helped to develop and I asked it to tell me what it could find out by studying the 301 historical values. It hesitated for a very brief amount of time and told me the following.

Here is the Actual /Fit and Forecast graph  [image]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awxKO.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbD0m.png and a less busy Actual/Forecast  [image] . The USEFUL equation that was found ( Note all models are "rong" but some are useful and some are very wrong ) is here in two parts. [image] and [image] providing clarity that the arima portion is simply (1,0,0) .

The statistics for the model are presented here [image]

The residuals look pristine [image] with a very clean acf [image] .

A closeup of the forecasts is here ....[image]

You said " I therefore applied a seasonal differencing for seasonality=43 " ... and I say that the data says no .

Periods 1-8 AND 36-43 ... are definitely non-players as they have little or no impact on what you are measuring.

It turns out your data had a lot to say about itself ...

With respect to your NON-SIGNIFICANT VARIANCE  ... this is probably due to a numerical flaw in the software that you used ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here you can find the raw data: http://pasted.co/93147588

Comment: If you like my answer ..please accept it and close the question

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I'm still trying to fully understand it, but in the meanwhile I accepted your answer.

Comment: If I can help please feel free to contact me via email ...in order to clear up any questions

Comment: or open up a new question ...and ask 1 or more so that you can better understand ... ... . If you can't frame the question perhaps dialogue would help. I am interested in what aspect of physics is this ..what were you measuring and how frequently

Comment: thanks for your interest. It is a magnetic signal from a plasma discharge on a Tokamak. In this case, the periodic activity is due to an instability of plasma which leads to rearrangement of the local magnetic field along with an outwards flux of heat. The shapes of the signal gives the name of sawtooth to this phenomenon.

What I understood is that an ARIMA(1,0,0) would be enough (and I found the same in my analysis) but I didn't get how you approached the seasonal part of the signal.
Also your "Periods 1-8 AND 36-43 ... are definitely non-players" sounds a bit obscure to me. Cheers!

Comment: send me an email and perhaps we can chat on SKYPE

Comment: The data suggests that there is a systematic cycle of 43 periods where periods1-8 and 36-43 do not materially effect the observations i.e. they are not significant. However there appears to be a deterministic effect e.g. a Monday effect on daily dales  for other periods in the cycle. This explains the saw-tooth appearance. This explains the saw-tooth phenomenon being "caused by an unspecified predictor" i.e an exogenous effect. ARIMA model treat all effects as endogenous while Intervention Detection leads to ARMAX models whose effects are latent and waiting to be discovered.

Comment: to put things in another light suppose your are analyzing daily sales and you find that tuesday's sales are always higher than any other day. After identifying the tuesday effect one would naturally be curious as to why? Upon research one might find that the owner of the store sets a lower price on Tuesday. IN tour case there is a background/unreported/exogenous series that is "causing" the effects . Note that it is not always a cycle of 43 but "close". Now that you have identified the presence of another variable,you might want to pursue "it" and use it to aid the prediction of your series,