# How to decide the order of ARIMA model based on the plots I have?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

[image]

[image]

[image]
Both the plots show very poor results for lags. Am I missing something in terms of transformation to get proper results?

Comment: Post your actual data.

Comment: @IrishStat: I have posted the data. Did you mean the actual data or just this?

Comment: ACTUAL OBSERVED DATA

Comment: @IrishStat: Sir, This is the actual observed data.

Comment: no you presented a picture of the actual data ..  i want the actual data i.e. the observed values

Answer (score 0):

before receipt of your actual recorded data ..

since your series has anomalies ( pulses to be sure ... ) possible seasonal pulses

since your series has possible change in error model variance over time ..

your acf is of little value as it is effected by non-gaussian structure.

correct model identification is done in a robust way.

see [I have correlogram ACF and PACF below for a temperature time series. Can I say it is MA(2) from ACF? What about AR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319732/i-have-correlogram-acf-and-pacf-below-for-a-temperature-time-series-can-i-say-i/319745#319745) for further comments.