# auto.arima returns a non-seasonal model even though I am forcing seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Per [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213201), you can force seasonality in auto.arima by selecting D=1.

I have a weekly time series which looks like it might (or might not) have a seasonal component (I have a priori reasons for thinking it might have a seasonal component).

```
Data <- as.ts(Data$Sales,order.by=Data$Date, frequency=52) 
Train <- window(Data,start=3,end=107)
Test <- window(Data,start=108,end=116)
```

I tried manually fitting a seasonal model:

```
fit <- arima(Train, order=c(2,0,1) , seasonal = list (order= c(0,1,0) , period = 52))
forec <- predict(fit, n.ahead =8)
```

gave an "OK" forecast (see first graph).

[image]

So I tried improving on it by using auto.arima to find the best model.

```
AutoFit <- auto.arima(Train)
```

This returned an ARIMA(1,1,1) model, which I then fit using:

```
#fit <- arima(Train, order=c(1,1,1))
```

But this gave worse results than the seasonal model I selected manually (see second graph). 
    [image]

So I tried to force seasonality by running:

```
AutoFit <- auto.arima(Train, D=1)
```

But I still get the same ARIMA(1,1,1) model.

Why is auto.arima not trying to fit a seasonal model, even why I try to force it?

I've also tried:

```
AutoFit <- auto.arima(Train, seasonal=TRUE, D=1)
```

and

```
AutoFit <- auto.arima(Train, seasonal=TRUE, start.P=0, start.Q=0 , D=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule number 1: when your code does not do what you want, start inspecting your objects.

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
(Data <- as.ts(rnorm(116), frequency=52) )
```

yields

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 116 
Frequency = 1
...snip...
```

Note that `Frequency` is 1, not 52, as we explicitly set above!

The problem is that `as.ts()` *silently* ignores the `frequency` parameter and sets the frequency to 1. Here is the help page to `stats::ts()`:

> ```
>  ‘as.ts’ is generic.  Its default method will use the ‘tsp’
>  attribute of the object if it has one to set the start and end
>  times and frequency.
> ```

So, if you want something seasonal, either supply an `x` with a `tsp` attribute to `as.ts()`... or use `ts()` straight from the beginning.

```
set.seed(1)
(Data <- ts(rnorm(116), frequency=52) )
```

which yields

```
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(3, 12) 
Frequency = 52
...snip...
```

This looks much better. Note that we now need to supply 2-vectors to `window()`, corresponding to the `Start` and `End` attributes of `Data`:

```
Train <- window(Data,start=c(1,1),end=c(2,52))
auto.arima(Train, D=1)
```

which yields a nice seasonal ARIMA model, as required:

```
Series: Train 
ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[52]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind 1) it is silly to try and fit a seasonal ar model of order 52 to 105 obvservations as you only have 2 cycles of data  and 2) see [I have correlogram ACF and PACF below for a temperature time series. Can I say it is MA(2) from ACF? What about AR?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319732/i-have-correlogram-acf-and-pacf-below-for-a-temperature-time-series-can-i-say-i/319745#319745) where ignoring the effect of anomalies is discussed causing a flaw in model identification

Comment: "it is silly to try and fit a seasonal ar model of order 52 to 105 obvservations as you only have 2 cycles of data" : I have a priori reasons for thinking my data might be seasonal, which is why I am trying a seasonal model even though I only have 2 years worth. Based on the graphs the seasonal does seem to work better.

Comment: You might try estimating a model including lag 52 and follow https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319254/if-i-am-convinced-that-a-series-is-mostly-trendseason-what-is-it-i-should-chec/319462#319462 for ways to improve that model . Alternatively you might set up a regression model with 51 weekly dummies and again consider model modifications per the url I cited. To a large degree due to the paucity of data , one needs to employ alternative approaches to construct a useful model and not depend on pseudo-automatic approaches designed for larger sample sizes like 10 years of weekly data..