# How to adjust for a temporary 12-month level shift in time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, outliers, univariate

I am working with a time series on monthly base (April 2004 - Oct 2016) in order to identify an ARIMA model and do forecasting.

This is the time series I examine:

month;volume
Apr 04;2.555
Mai 04;2.58
Jun 04;2.617
Jul 04;2.577
Aug 04;2.654
Sep 04;2.603
Okt 04;2.694
Nov 04;2.757
Dez 04;2.699
Jan 05;2.723
Feb 05;2.658
Mrz 05;2.739
Apr 05;2.748
Mai 05;2.813
Jun 05;2.751
Jul 05;2.812
Aug 05;2.758
Sep 05;2.726
Okt 05;2.681
Nov 05;2.887
Dez 05;2.926
Jan 06;2.933
Feb 06;2.852
Mrz 06;2.939
Apr 06;2.768
Mai 06;2.869
Jun 06;2.822
Jul 06;2.907
Aug 06;3.491
Sep 06;3.531
Okt 06;3.532
Nov 06;3.568
Dez 06;3.585
Jan 07;3.626
Feb 07;3.61
Mrz 07;3.594
Apr 07;3.641
Mai 07;3.687
Jun 07;3.728
Jul 07;3.734
Aug 07;3.261
Sep 07;3.191
Okt 07;3.351
Nov 07;3.344
Dez 07;3.344
Jan 08;3.363
Feb 08;3.334
Mrz 08;3.393
Apr 08;3.401
Mai 08;3.429
Jun 08;3.398
Jul 08;3.481
Aug 08;3.523
Sep 08;3.476
Okt 08;3.571
Nov 08;3.437
Dez 08;3.54
Jan 09;3.516
Feb 09;3.422
Mrz 09;3.479
Apr 09;3.421
Mai 09;3.431
Jun 09;3.456
Jul 09;3.539
Aug 09;3.54
Sep 09;3.491
Okt 09;3.552
Nov 09;3.513
Dez 09;3.581
Jan 10;3.586
Feb 10;3.49
Mrz 10;3.591
Apr 10;3.579
Mai 10;3.66
Jun 10;3.612
Jul 10;3.707
Aug 10;3.765
Sep 10;3.692
Okt 10;3.793
Nov 10;3.782
Dez 10;3.804
Jan 11;3.835
Feb 11;3.742
Mrz 11;3.802
Apr 11;3.822
Mai 11;3.907
Jun 11;3.873
Jul 11;3.955
Aug 11;4.015
Sep 11;3.944
Okt 11;4.08
Nov 11;3.979
Dez 11;4.053
Jan 12;4.102
Feb 12;4.001
Mrz 12;4.084
Apr 12;4.103
Mai 12;4.131
Jun 12;4.136
Jul 12;4.252
Aug 12;4.256
Sep 12;4.207
Okt 12;4.321
Nov 12;4.393
Dez 12;4.372
Jan 13;4.386
Feb 13;4.299
Mrz 13;4.394
Apr 13;4.419
Mai 13;4.475
Jun 13;4.436
Jul 13;4.568
Aug 13;4.589
Sep 13;4.553
Okt 13;4.602
Nov 13;4.538
Dez 13;4.584
Jan 14;4.599
Feb 14;4.497
Mrz 14;4.636
Apr 14;4.632
Mai 14;4.668
Jun 14;4.681
Jul 14;4.75
Aug 14;4.772
Sep 14;4.745
Okt 14;4.854
Nov 14;4.774
Dez 14;4.865
Jan 15;4.872
Feb 15;4.766
Mrz 15;4.89
Apr 15;4.925
Mai 15;5.005
Jun 15;5.003
Jul 15;5.074
Aug 15;5.089
Sep 15;5.027
Okt 15;5.132
Nov 15;5.11
Dez 15;5.179
Jan 16;5.19
Feb 16;5.148
Mrz 16;5.221
Apr 16;5.253
Mai 16;5.359
Jun 16;5.27
Jul 16;5.34
Aug 16;5.368
Sep 16;5.314
Okt 16;5.436

My data contains a significant level shift during a period of 12 month (Aug 2006 - July 2007), afterwards it is returning to its previous level, see the graph:

[image]

I assume a change in measurement to be responsible for this shift. The level shift is making the identification of an adequate ARIMA model impossible. Therefore, I want to adjust the data of this period.

So far, I simply subtracted 15 from the 12 outlier observations (y_adjusted = y - 15) which delivers quite reasonable results:

[image]

Nevertheless, this procedure was not at all based on econometric principles, but rather a successful "error-and-trial". Do you have any suggestion how to compute this adjustment formally?

Comment: If you are happy with my answer .. uptick it and accept it to close the question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of the knowledge of the event , what you are looking for is a  procedure to simultaneously identify and refine an arima model AND also automatically identify and include 2 level/step shift indicators (possibly collapsing into 1).... reflecting the temporary effect via Intervention Detection procedures http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html . If you post your actual data in a column oriented csv file I will try to help you further.

Alternatively if you are aware of the timing and length of the intervention you can construct an X variable of the form ...0,0,0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1,...0,0,0,0,0,
detailing the known beginning and termination points and then try to identify the arima portion of this armaX model.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF DATA:

The data that you posted is different from the graph you posted.

Here is a graph of the data you posted which is the data I analyzed.

[image]

Your data suggest the need for a differencing factor of order 1 ....thus a level shift detection requires 2 pulses. When you difference a step/level you get a pulse ... thus a model that has differencing requires pulses to reflect the abrupt upwards effect and the abrupt downwards effect. A partial picture of the model is here [image] .. .272 up and .241 down suggesting a different return to the baseline.

I submitted the 151 monthly numbers to my favorite time series program and it automatically developed a use model .Here is the Actual/Fit and Forecast graph [image] and less cluttered here [image].

The equation is here  [image] detailing four seasonal pulses covering Feb, Sept and Nov suggesting non-seasonal activity for the other 9 months and 4 additional pulses .

Note that the differencing operator is distributed across all series in the equation. Also note that {1-B}level = pulse thus  {1-B]pulse = {1-B}{1-B}level . The AUTOBOX equation shows {1-B}pulse which if you wish can be restated as {1-B}{1-B}level .

Restated a pulse in a non-stationary can be interpreted as an intercept change. Visually one can confirm the identified Pulses as points of change for the model-implied intercept.

A significant change in error variance (downwards) was found at or about time period 60. [image]

The mo[image]del statistics are here and here [image]

The forecasts are detailed here [image] .

EDITED TO ANSWER THE OP'S COMMENT

Adjusting the 12 observations and then identifying an ARIMA model is a sound approach. The only problem is there are 4 seasonal factors ( seasonal pulses ) and 3 pulses that need to be adjusted for before identifying the first difference model (0,1,0)(0,0,0) with a constant while dealing with a non-constant error variance. Your resultant ACF of the er[image]rors should look something like this ...suggesting sufficiency.

By the way .. why did you post data that was different from your graph  ????

Comment: Thanks IrishStat for your answer. I added my data to the question.

Acutally, I already computed a SARIMAX estimation including a dummy for the Intervention period. The dummy's coefficient is highly significant, but I am not sure how to Interpret these results.

Comment: Your comments are very useful, thanks. As I dont have Autobox available unfortunately, I would like to simplify your demonstration. Im thinking about introducing 2 terms for the level shift in my SARIMA-equation like Tsay suggested in his paper. This would allow me to identify the upwards/downwards effects as you did. Applying these knowledge to my data, I would estimate a SARIMA model of the modified data. 
I am aware of the (over?) simplification of doing so, but I guess that this approach would be acceptable for my purpose. Or do you see any huge disadvantages of proceeding like this?

Comment: The data in the graph was the original one. The csv showed the log data (which I am actually working with in order to stabilize the increasing variance of the series).

So , I will try my best to realize your recommendations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a "rookie mistake" to determine power transforms from the original data https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers . transforms should be based upon the errors from the model because that is where the assumptions are in effect. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319254/if-i-am-convinced-that-a-series-is-mostly-trendseason-what-is-it-i-should-chec/319462#319462 for a step-by-step

Comment: Also see http://autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation starting at slide 61 to understand that the original data (untreatred for anomalies) can incorrectly suggest the need for a power transform.